# Is it possible to have Windows display a popup window when a server is being rebooted/shut down?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Basically what I want to do is this:

When somebody tries to reboot a server, before the shutdown/reboot process actually begins, a warning window will popup saying "Have you stopped X service before rebooting? Click Okay to continue with shut down or Cancel to cancel the shut down and stop the service before attempting to shut down the system again."

Is something like this even possible or is this just a far-fetched dream?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always build your own scripts that will shut these services down for you when you double-click them to reboot the server.  I'm assuming that you want this to occur because you have some services that are interdependent on each other.  Exchange 2003 is an infamous example of this.

Something like [this](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Accelerating_Exchange_Shut_Down.html) which was build for shutting down Exchange 2003, or [this](http://www.amset.info/exchange/shutdown-script.asp).

Comment: It is because one of our servers has a proprietary software called NimbraVision on it. If NimbraVision isn't properly shutdown before being shutting down the server it can cause the mysql database it uses to be corrupted.

Since our NOC guys have to use this server I can't properly control this.

I think I will remove the Log Off/Shutdown buttons from the Start Menu, and add a desktop shortcut script like you mentioned...hopefully that should resolve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for adding a shutdown script.  Get your NOC guys to give you the proper commands to do your shutdown.